# SQL Server 2005 - Join does not terminate - Speed issue?

Tags: sql-server-2005, join

does anybody have an idea why this join operation does not terminate:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT LOWER([Computer Name]) AS 'cname' FROM table1)
AS export,
(SELECT AssetID AS 'CCID', Hostname AS 'cname' FROM table2 WHERE LastVersionFlag=1)
AS known

WHERE export.cname = LEFT(known.cname, LEN(export.cname));
```

The problem which I want to solve is:

- Table1 column "cname" contains: "pc1"
- Table2 column "hostname" contains: "pc1.domain.com"
- Table2 also contains column "CCID": 123123

As result of the query I need to receive the CCID of each "cname" from table1.

EDIT:

The query is running for >15minutes now and produces no output, nor terminates.

- Table1 contains about 100.000rows
- Table2 contains about 200.000rows

Any ideas how to speed up the query?!

EDIT2:

Indices are put on Table1 cname and Table2 cname

The task schedule looks like this: http://i55.tinypic.com/1z3o0t4.png

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for, a basic join?

```
SELECT known.CCID, export.[Computer Name] AS cname 
FROM
table1 AS export
INNER JOIN table2 AS known ON LOWER(export.[Computer Name]) = LOWER(LEFT(known.cname, LEN(export.[Computer Name])))
WHERE LastVersionFlag=1
```

**Edit:**
Here are some suggestions for speeding up the query:

Firstly, the string operation in the join are very costly.  You can avoid having to call lower() if you force a case insensitive collation for the join.

e.g. `...ON known.cname = export.[Computed Column] collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AS_KI_WI`

Your best move would be to create a persisted computed column on table2 that just contains the cname using your formula from the join `LEFT(known.cname, LEN(export.[Computer Name]))` , then you can put an index on the computed column as well as the cname column of table1.  Once done, your join will be a simple equality instead of a heavily manipulated comparison.  This will allow the query engine to make a more optimized plan.

Comment: Exactly. As far as I can see your query performs the same action as mine and also does not terminate...

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by "doesn't terminate"?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your query does not perform because of the size of the data.

It needs to generate the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of 100.000 * 200.000 rows, and then apply the WHERE conditions.

SQL Server comparison is case-insensitive if the column's collation is set to case-insensitive (defaulted by database and server collations).

To speed up the join operation, add (unique?) indexes on table1.[Computer Name] and table2.Hostname.

Modify your query to

```
SELECT known.CCID, export.[Computer Name] AS cname 
FROM table1 AS export
INNER JOIN table2 AS known 
    ON known.Hostname LIKE export.[Computer Name] + '%' 
    AND LastVersionFlag=1
```

If all your hostnames use dotted cname notation, use '.%'.

Comment: Thanks for this input, I adjusted my query accordingly. Nevertheless it needs ~20minutes for processing and returns an empty result set. I have no explanation for this since there are matches within the two tables...

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note: SQL Server is working in case insensitive mode by default (if you didn't do any changes), so you dont have to care about upper/lower-case normally. **Using functions like `LOWER` prevents the usage of indexes.**

And to speed up the last `WHERE`, you could rewrite it with a `LIKE` that will take advantage of an index on the involved columns (if you got one). That would be something like (as in devio's answer):

```
known.cname LIKE (export.cname + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Bringing all suggestions together would give you following query.
With proper indexing and the number of records you mention, it shouldn't take minutes to return the results.

```
SELECT  cname = t1.[Computer Name] 
        , CCID = k.AssetID
        , Hostname = k.cname
FROM    table1 t1
        INNER JOIN known k ON k.Hostname LIKE t1.[Computer Name]  + '%'
WHERE   k.LastVersionFlag = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this input, I adjusted my query accordingly. Nevertheless it needs ~20minutes for processing and returns an empty result set. I have no explanation for this since there are matches within the two tables...

Comment: @Michael, could you show us the output of a SHOWPLAN statement.

Comment: Is the Showplan different to the plan which I have posted as edit in topic?